# Problems with adding multiple html files on Mosync

Tags: javascript, html, mosync

i'm new to Mosync and i'm trying to create an HTML5/Javascript project. The IDE generates a main.cpp file and an index.html file.

The main.cpp file contains a reference for the index.html file; i've already tried creating a new html file inside the same folder where the generated index.html file is and changed the reference in the main.cpp file to call the file that i've just created but it gives me an error that says the file cannot be found.

I've even tried removing all the code in the generate index.html file and running it and the results still shows all the deleted code from the index.html file.

My question would be how do i add multiple html files when creating a MoSync project?

Answer (score 0):

It should work to do what you are doing, this could be a bug. Can you provide some details about which version of MoSync you are using, and which platform?

You should be able to have any html file in the folder LocalFiles in a MoSync project, and then just pass the file name to showPage in main.cpp, just as you are doing.

Perhaps the project is not rebuild properly? Try to right-click on the project in Eclipse, then select Rebuild. Are you on iOS or Android? How do you transfer the app to the device?

Answer (score 0):

As Mikael mentioned also, I think it is an IDE bug, I tried refreshing/rebuilding the project and it worked fine. Sometimes eclipse does not detect file changes that come from other editors so it ignores them.